# Replace dots in php strings with underscores without str_replace

Tags: php

I have an array which contain strings and some of that string contains dots ( '.' ).

And I must repeat. I don't want to do this with str_replace.

So, I need to replace that dots with underscores.

For example:

```
for($data as $key=>$value){
   print_r($value);
}
```

Lets say how output is:

```
'Hello. I have two dots. Please replace them!'
```

And what would like we to have is:

```
'Hello_ I have two dots_ Please replace them!'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `preg_replace` instead ?

Comment: preg_replace('/\./', '_', $value); but why not str_replace()?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran to me it looks like a school work assignment. maybe teacher want them to treat strings like char arrays or something. i just posted a solution if thats the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

is this a codegolf or something?

anyway here's *a* solution:

```
$text='Hello. I have two dots. Please replace them!';

echo IHateStrReplace(".","_",$text);

function IHateStrReplace($replace_from,$replace_to,$input)
{
    $result="";

    for($i=0;$i<strlen($input);$i++)
    {
        $result.= ($input[$i]==$replace_from)?$replace_to:$input[$i];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

http://3v4l.org/Cjp4G

Comment: Voted up for the function name `IHateStrReplace` :)

Comment: Likewise.  preg_replace aside, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
$original_string = 'Hello. I have two dots. Please replace them!';
$exploded_string = explode('.' , $original_string);
$new_string = implode('_' , $exploded_string);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo strtr('Hello. I have two dots. Please replace them!', '.', '_');
```

[String Translate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) does a byte-by-byte translation of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace. https://www.php.net/preg_replace

```
$var = 'Hello. I have two dots. Please replace them!';
echo preg_replace('#\.#', '_', $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is overkill for replacing a single character but if you have to avoid `str_replace()` then this will do it:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $data[$key] = preg_replace('/\./', '_', $value);
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers, `strtr()` (string translate) translates single characters, so combining it with array_map makes for a neat solution:

```
// Push every item in the array through strtr()
$array = array_map('strtr', $array, ['.', '_']);
```

However, in benchmarking I've found `strtr()` to be slower than `str_replace()`, so I tend to use that instead.